# Find distinct arrays with Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider this code

```
String[] colours1 = new String[]{"red", "green", "blue"};
String[] colours2 = new String[]{"red", "yellow", "blue"};
String[] colours3 = new String[]{"red", "green", "blue"};

List<String[]> distinct = Stream.of(colours1, colours2, colours3)
        .distinct() // Do something here to compare arrays better
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want the `distinct` list to contain only 2 elements `colours1` and `colours2` (as 1 and 3 are equivalent). However because the stream `distinct()` method performs equals comparison it still contains all 3 colours arrays. I want a custom distinct function where you can provide a comparator. In this case `Objects#deepEquals` would be sufficient. Is there a easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the arrays in lists, use `distinct()`, unwrap them again:

```
Stream.of(colours1, colours2, colours3)
    .map(Arrays::asList)
    .distinct()
    .map(list -> list.toArray(new String[0]))
    .collect(toList())
```

This works because [`List.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) considers two lists equal if they have the same contents (the same number of elements, and equality of the elements at corresponding positions in the two lists).

However, this doesn't return the same array instances. If you need (some of) the same array instances in the final list, you can do something like so:

```
class MyArrayList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
  final T[] arr;

  MyArrayList(T[] arr) { this.arr = arr; }
  @Override public int size() { return arr.length; }
  @Override public T get(int i) { return arr[i]; }
}

List<String> distinct =
    Stream.of(colours1, colours2, colours3)
        .map(MyArrayList::new)
        .distinct()
        .map(el -> el.arr)
        .collect(toList());
```